# Synchronize files from Box.com to AEM DAM

Tags: aem, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream, box

I am trying to sync the files from my Box.com account to AEM(CQ5) DAM. I have written a service where I am able to authenticate to Box.com and get the files. But in order for me to upload those into AEM DAM, I need the files as InputStream. On Box.com documentation(https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk/blob/master/doc/files.md), I find the code snippet for Downloading a file.

```
BoxFile file = new BoxFile(api, "id");
BoxFile.Info info = file.getInfo();

FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(info.getName());
file.download(stream);
stream.close();
```

But I could not find anything where I can get the file in Inputstream so that I can use it to upload it into AEM DAM. When I tried to convert from OutputStream to Inputstream, its just not really working and creating ZERO bytes files in AEM.

Any pointers and help greatly appreciated !

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where I tried to create a CSV within CQ and store it in JCR. The solutions are piped Streams:

```
final PipedInputStream pis = new PipedInputStream();
final PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream(pis);
```

Though I then used an OutputStreamWriter to write into the output stream, but the FileOutputStream.download should work as well.

To actually write into JCR you need the ValueFactory, which you can get from a JCR Session (here the example for my CSV):

```
ValueFactory valueFactory = session.getValueFactory();
Node fileNode = logNode.addNode("log.csv", "nt:file");
Node resNode = fileNode.addNode("jcr:content", "nt:resource");
resNode.setProperty("jcr:mimeType", "text/plain");
resNode.setProperty("jcr:data", valueFactory.createBinary(pis));
session.save();
```

EDIT: untested example with BoxFile:

```
try {
    AssetManager assetManager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(AssetManager.class);
    BoxFile file = new BoxFile(api, "id");
    BoxFile.Info info = file.getInfo();

    final PipedInputStream pis = new PipedInputStream();
    final PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream(pis);
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            file.download(pos);
        }
    });

    Asset asset = assetManager.createAsset(info.getName(), pis, info.getMimeType(), true);

    IOUtils.closeQuietly(pos);
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(pis);
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOGGER.error("could not download file: ", e);
}
```

Comment: Hey Thomas.. Thanks for the reply. But the problem that I am facing right now is that Box provides the file in FileOutputStream object that I need to convert to FileInputStream that can directly be used to be uploaded into AEM. AssetManager API provides a method createAsset() to do that and it takes care of creating the proper JCR structure as well.

So, the main issue is that how do I use the FileOutputStream to be put into AEM.

Comment: @AbhinitBhatnagar I added an untested example code, maybe you can start from there.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the code correctly you are downloading the file to a file named info.getName(). Try using **FileInputStream(info.getName())** to get the input stream from the downloaded file.

```
BoxFile file = new BoxFile(api, "id");
BoxFile.Info info = file.getInfo();

FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(info.getName());
file.download(stream);
stream.close();
InputStream inStream=new FileInputStream(info.getName());
```